# Posting data to the database from mvc form

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to save contact data from an MVC form to a sql database. I am also saving the data to an XML document. The XML document is created correctly with the correct data, but I am not getting the data to the database. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Controller handling Contact data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TestProject.Models;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Rabbit.Bootstrap;

namespace TestProject.Controllers
{
    public class ContactsController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Contact contact = new Contact();

            return View(contact);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(Contact c)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string ContactFileName = Path.GetFileName(String.Format("{0} {1}.xml", c.LastName, c.FirstName));
                ContactFileName = (@"C:\Users\kevin.schultz\TestDocuments\" + ContactFileName);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(ContactFileName))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The file already exists. A number will be added to create a unique file name", "Important", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

                    int i = 0;
                    while (System.IO.File.Exists(ContactFileName))
                    {
                        ContactFileName = String.Format("{0} - {1}", ContactFileName, i.ToString());
                        i++;
                    }
                }

                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(c.GetType());
                StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(ContactFileName);
                ser.Serialize(myWriter, c);
                myWriter.Close();
                return View("ContactSuccess");

            }
            return View("ContactError");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Save()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Save (Contact s)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (ContactDataEntities CustData = new ContactDataEntities())
                    {
                        CustData.dbContacts.Add(
                            new dbContact()
                            {
                                FirstName = s.FirstName,
                                LastName = s.LastName,
                                PhoneHome = s.PhoneHome,
                                PhoneCell = s.PhoneCell,
                                Email = s.Email,
                                Address = s.Address,
                                City = s.City,
                                State = s.State,
                                ZipCode = s.ZipCode,
                            });
                        CustData.SaveChanges();

                        return View("ContactSuccess");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return View("ContactError");
                }
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You are missing data, please ensure all fields are correct.", "Important", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Database

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] (
    [Id]        INT  NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] TEXT NOT NULL,
    [LastName]  TEXT NOT NULL,
    [PhoneHome] TEXT NOT NULL,
    [PhoneCell] TEXT NOT NULL,
    [Email]     TEXT NOT NULL,
    [Address]   TEXT NOT NULL,
    [City]      TEXT NOT NULL,
    [State]     TEXT NOT NULL,
    [ZipCode]   TEXT NOT NULL,
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestProject.Models
{

        public class Contact 
        {
            [Required]
            [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
            [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid First Name")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid Last Name")]
            [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
            [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 2)]
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid Home Phone Number including area code")]
            [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
            public string PhoneHome { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid Cell Phone Number")]
            [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
            public string PhoneCell { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid Email Address")]
            [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid Street Address")]
            [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
            [StringLength(120, MinimumLength = 4)]
            public string Address { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid City Name")]
            [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
            [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 2)]
            public string City { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid State Abbreviation")]
            [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
            [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 2)]
            public string State { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter A Valid 5 Digit Zip Code")]
            [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
            public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        }


    }
```

View

```
@model TestProject.Models.Contact

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h4>Company Contact Form</h4>
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <form class="form-primary">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="form-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, "First Name", new { style = "display:inline;" })
            </div>
            <div class="form.field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { placeholder = "First Name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>

        <div class="form-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, "Last Name", new { style = "display:inline;" })
        </div>

        <div class="form.field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="form-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneHome, "Home Phone", new { style = "display:inline;" })
        </div>

        <div class="form.field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneHome)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneHome)
        </div>

        <div class="form-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneCell, "Cell Phone", new { style = "display:inline;" })
        </div>

        <div class="form.field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneCell)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneCell)
        </div>

        <div class="form-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, "Email Address", new { style = "display:inline;" })
        </div>

        <div class="form.field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

        <div class="form-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, "Street Address", new { style = "display:inline;" })
        </div>

        <div class="form.field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
        </div>

        <div class="form-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, "City", new { style = "display:inline;" })
        </div>

        <div class="form.field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
        </div>

        <div class="form-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, "State", new { style = "display:inline;" })
        </div>

        <div class="form.field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)
        </div>

        <div class="form-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ZipCode, "Zip Code", new { style = "display:inline;" })
        </div>

        <div class="form.field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ZipCode)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ZipCode)

        </div>

    <br />
    <div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn-custom" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" class="btn-custom" value="Clear" />
    </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
}
```

Comment: Have you run it in the debugger?  Do you get an error?  Are you using a SQL Server or a local file?  Hard to diagnose multi-tier issues from just a code dump.

Comment: I think it's because you are posting data to Index action and that action is saving data to the xml, not to database. Are you unable to save to database when you post to Save action? Are you getting into Save action? So, more details please.

Comment: I'm also not seeing any noticeable problem here. However, there's a few things worth pointing out: 1) Your file writing is not thread-safe. Even though you're appending a number you could still get collisions. Granted, it would require two individuals with the same name posting at the same time, which isn't very likely, but perhaps something like a double-post could cause an error. 2) It's a bad idea to use `using` for EF work. Either create your context as an instance variable or inject it into your controller. 3) `Html.BeginForm` outputs a `<form>` element, so you have two in your view.

Comment: I used debugger and the application completes without errors prior to writing to the database but after creating the XML file. As for posting to the save action, I am not sure how to tell if I am getting into the save action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually called the save to the database method. Here is what I would suggest:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(Contact c)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //should use client side validation for this as well.
            MessageBox.Show("You are missing data, please ensure all fields are correct.", "Important", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        return View();
    }
    SaveToXml(c);
    return SaveToDatabase(c);

}

public void SaveToXml(Contact c)
{
    string ContactFileName = Path.GetFileName(String.Format("{0} {1}.xml", c.LastName, c.FirstName));
    ContactFileName = (@"C:\Users\kevin.schultz\TestDocuments\\" + ContactFileName);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(ContactFileName))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The file already exists. A number will be added to create a unique file name", "Important", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

        int i = 0;
        while (System.IO.File.Exists(ContactFileName))
        {
            ContactFileName = String.Format("{0} - {1}", ContactFileName, i.ToString());
            i++;
        }
    }

    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(c.GetType());
    StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(ContactFileName);
    ser.Serialize(myWriter, c);
    myWriter.Close();
}

public ActionResult SaveToDatabase(Contact s)
{
    try
    {
        using (ContactDataEntities CustData = new ContactDataEntities())
        {
            CustData.dbContacts.Add(
                new dbContact()
                {
                    FirstName = s.FirstName,
                    LastName = s.LastName,
                    PhoneHome = s.PhoneHome,
                    PhoneCell = s.PhoneCell,
                    Email = s.Email,
                    Address = s.Address,
                    City = s.City,
                    State = s.State,
                    ZipCode = s.ZipCode,
                });
            CustData.SaveChanges();

            return View("ContactSuccess");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View("ContactError");
    }
}
```

I refactored a little for clarity. You never called your save method from your view, so I ran on the assumption you wanted to save both on one click. The \ is escaping the \ tag mainly because Stackoverflow doesn't recognize the \" as being a closed quotes (\is also the escape character)